Relationship between transition functions and change of frames by multiplying with a matrix-valued function in a vector bundle
Let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle of rank $k$ over some field, say $\mathbb R$.
In general if $U \subset M$ is an open set over which there exists a frame, call it $F = (e_1, \ldots, e_k)$ with $e_i \in \Gamma(U,E)$, and $g: U \rightarrow GL(k, \mathbb R)$, define a new frame, call it $Fg$, by the formula:
$$
Fg = (\sum_{s=1}^k g^{s,1} e_s, \ldots, \sum_{s=1}^k g^{s, k} e_s)
$$
where $g^{s,l}$ is the $(s,l)$ entry of the matrix-valued function $g$.
In other words, if $M$ is the "matrix" formed with the frame $F$, having "columns" $e_1, \ldots, e_k$, then the $l$-th element of the new frame will be $col_l (M g)$.
Now let $\{ (U_i, \phi_i) \}_i$ be a trivialisation, where for each $i$, $\phi_i: \pi^{-1}(U_i) \rightarrow U_i \times \mathbb R^k$.
For $U_i \cap U_j \neq \emptyset$, denote the trivialisation functions by $g_{i,j}: U_i \cap U_j \rightarrow GL(k, \mathbb R)$. These are obtained at each $x \in U_i \cap U_j$ as:
$$
g_{i,j}(x):= (\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}): \{ x \} \times \mathbb R^k \rightarrow \{ x \} \times \mathbb R^k
$$
Here, $g_{i,j}$ is seen as acting from the left on column vectors in $\mathbb R^k$. I also consider $g_{i,j}$ as a matrix with respect to the standard basis in $\mathbb R^k$.
Consider a basis $\{ e_l^0 \}$ in $\mathbb R^k$ and denote its matrix $B$. On $U_i \cap U_j$,  put:
$$
F^i(x) := (\phi_i^{-1}(x, e_1^0), \ldots, \phi_i^{-1}(x, e_k^0) ), \quad \forall x \in U_i \cap U_j
$$
and define similarly $F^j$.
I'm trying to prove a formula relating the frames $F^i$ and $F^j$ using $g_{i,j}$ and the multiplication $Fg$ that I defined in the beginning of my question. Intuition says that the relationship should be
$$
F^j = F^i g_{i,j}
$$
(or maybe with $g_{j,i}$ instead of $g_{i,j}$), but trying to prove any of these seemingly simple formulae led me to desperate calculations which don't seem to lead anywhere.
My attempt is as follows:
I apply $\phi_i$ to $(F^i g_{i,j})_l$ (i.e. to the $l$-th element in the frame $F^i g_{i,j}$). We observe that
$$
\phi_i \left( (F^i g_{i,j})_l \right) = col_l (B g_{i,j})
$$
where $B$ is the matrix of the chosen, fixed basis in $\mathbb R^k$.
The problem is that to apply $g_{i,j}$ as the isomorphism $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}$, it needs to act on column vectors from the left, not from the right, as it does in the above formula.
The only thing I could think of, then, was to try and prove that
$$
F^j = F^i (g_{i,j})^T
$$
instead, using that
$$
lin_l (B (g_{i,j})^) = (g_{i,j} (lin_l B)^T )^T
$$
Now we could apply $g_{i,j}$ to the column vector $(lin_l B)^T$, but the problem is that the result is not something nice, because that line vector is obtained as the $l$-th components of all the different elements in the frame $F^i$, and not, as one would hope, as all the components of the single element $F^i_l$.
If form on the onset I pick $B$ to be symmetric, then the calculations simplify because
$$
(lin_l B)^T = col_l B
$$
so then
$$
B g_{i,j}^T = (\phi_j(e^i_1), \ldots, \phi_j(e^i_k))
$$
and hence
$$
\phi_i\left( (F^i g_{i,j}^T)_l \right)
=
\phi_j(e_l^i)
$$
which leads to
$$
(F^i g_{i,j}^T)_l = \phi_i^{-1} \circ \phi_j(e_l^i)
$$
which suggests that maybe I should try to prove the formula for $(g_{i,j}^T)^{-1}$ instead of $g_{i,j}^T$? Either way, this would not do away with the fact that I would have to choose $B$ symmetric, would it?
